Can I use Microsoft's CA3001 code analysis rule in .NET Framework?
Can I use Microsoft's CA3xxx code analysis rules in .NET Framework 4.x?  They don't show up in my ruleset:

Is there a way to bring them in?  Is this documented anywhere?  SO and Google searches are unhelpful; most search results seem to be concerned with fixing them or turning them off.
